# Finding a subdirectory that matches a file name

Tags: python, list, match

I'm pretty new to python, so I would be grateful for any help. What I'm trying to do is find a subdirectory in the specified directory matching the title of the specified zip file. There is definitely a folder titled "1008" in the "projects" folder so I'm not sure what's wrong.

Here is the code:

```
import os

zipFiles = r'C:\temp\Python_Test\Zipped_Files\1008.zip'
prjFolder = r'C:\temp\Python_Test\Projects'
prjNum = os.path.basename(zipFiles)
prjNum = os.path.splitext(prjNum)
prjNum = prjNum[0]
prjList = os.walk(prjFolder).next()[1]
prjList = map(int, prjList)

if prjNum in prjList:
    print "Yes"
else:
    print "No"
```

Comment: `projNum` is a string but you are looking it up in a list of integers.

Comment: Perfect! Totally a rookie mistake. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already know the name of the directory you are looking for, just check to see if it exists

```
import os

zipFiles = r'C:\temp\Python_Test\Zipped_Files\1008.zip'
prjFolder = r'C:\temp\Python_Test\Projects'
prjNum = os.path.basename(zipFiles)
prjNum = os.path.splitext(prjNum)
prjNum = prjNum[0]
print os.path.isdir(os.path.join(prjFolder, prjNum))
```

Comment: Yes, that's much more efficient. Thank you.